# Why do I need to enter the captcha n times to figure out that my n tags are not created yet?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, captcha

When asking a question on Stack Overflow, I need to enter the captcha before it tells me a tag is not created yet. But it tells me only one tag is not created yet, so I need to enter the captcha again before finding out my other tag is also not created yet.

Comment: When you type in a tag already existing ones come up...

Comment: @Ben: Oh thanks, I didn't think of that at the time because I wasn't aware such so had such bad behavior, nor did I even know that I needed privileges to create new tags. /thread